# How to evaluate the operation of a differential form on a vector?

Tags: vector-analysis, differential-forms, discrete-calculus

While studying some Discrete Calculus following Grady and Polimeni (2010), I've found the following problem. I would like to know how the author found the result w(v) = -8. I've found that the vector v (given by the cross product definition) is given by [3 e1 ; -1 e2; 2 e3]. Is this right also?

Thanks in advance.

[Problem Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMJh8.png)

where:

[Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXvna.png)

Comment: Typo: w(v) = -8

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  You can edit typos by clicking 'edit'.  Also, it's generally better to type things in [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) rather than attaching an image when possible.  It makes things searchable and people are more likely to answer a question when they don't need to go back and forth between images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINTS**

- What is 
  $$
  \bar{e_i}\wedge \bar{e_j} \wedge \tilde{\sigma}^m\tilde{\sigma}^n
  $$
- What is
  $$2\cdot 7 + 3\cdot(-6) + (-1)\cdot 4 $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints. Gotcha!